# Python Equivalent to Javascript querySelector

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

In the Google Chrome's Inspect element tool you can: `right-click on an element > copy > copy js path` and you get a nice snippet of code like the following: `document.querySelector("#left-container > div.left-content > div > div > ul")` that easily gives you the "path" to a selected element in Javascript.

My question is if there is an easy way to turn this javascript snippet into Python possibly using BeautifulSoup that can give me the elements I want from a webpage.

Comment: The argument to `bs.select()` is a CSS selector just like that.

Comment: Can you expand on this: _I always struggle to get the elements that I want out of BeautifulSoup_ ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BeautifulSoup has [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) support - use `select()` or `select_one()` methods:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.select("#left-container > div.left-content > div > div > ul")
```

Make sure to use version 4.7.0 or above to have support for the most CSS4 selectors.